# Pimcore data types inheritance

Tags: pimcore

I'm confused about academy's question "Which data types do support data inheritance?"
After I've listened to all the videos and read all the documentation about this chapter I still get error on this question.

I tried to answer with **Blocks** and **Object Bricks** as documentation mentioned, but still get an error.

[image: a multiple choice question]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please link the related documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

every data type does, except fieldcollections

Answer (score 5):

MickSt is right, all except Field Collections.

The academy videos are in most cases very confusing, at least to me. What helps is to practice yourself with some custom classes. Create an instance of a custom class with all those data types and then create a child instance. You will quickly see which types get inherited and which don't.